# Trying to get Scanner to scan entire file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
String userInput = stdin.nextLine();                        
file = new File(userInput);

Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);    
while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {                  
    fileContents = fileScanner.nextLine();
}
```

So I'm trying to figure out how I can get my variable `fileContents` to hold all of the file  from the scanner. with the current way I have it setup the variable `fileContents` is left with only the last line of the .txt file. for what I'm doing I need it to hold the entire text from the file. spaces, chars and all.

I'm sure there is a simple fix to this I'm just very new to java/coding.

Comment: fileContents is already declared as a String earlier

Comment: Why use `File` in 2015? You use Java 7+, right?

Comment: I'm in my first programming class. This is what they are teaching us at the moment.

Comment: Look into StringBuilder and append()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
fileContents += fileScanner.nextLine();
```

or

```
 fileContents  =fileContents + fileScanner.nextLine();
```

With your approach you are reassigning the `fileContents` value instead you need to concat the next line.

Comment: I LOVE YOU SO MUCH RIGHT NOW

Answer (score 0):

```
        String userInput = stdin.nextLine();                        
        file = new File(userInput);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);    
        while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(fileScanner.nextLine()+"\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Or follow the @singhakash's answer, because his one is faster performance wise I presume. But I used a StringBuilder to give you an idea that you're 'appending' or in other words, just adding to the data that you wish to use. Where as with your way, you're going to be getting the last line of the text because it keeps overriding the previous data.

Comment: I'm going to keep this post for later. I'm only 4 weeks into my first programming class and still a noob to most syntax. thank you very much though for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use below as well:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/abc.txt"));
String fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

You don't have to use while loop in this case.

Comment: that looks like amazing stuff. I'm only 4 weeks into a intro java course (which is my first coding experience) and I'm supposed to try to keep it limited to what we have learned thus far. thank you though!

Comment: That's fine. Just wanted to let you know the shortcut.